# mysql query with array returning first 3 coulmn without validation

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I m joing table replies and table discussion where discussion have four row ie 1, 2,3,4 
and i have foreign key to but it only return first 3 database row.. without even match

```
 public function getReplies(array $id)
{
        //problem in this query
    $sql="SELECT r.*,u.*,d.* from tbl_replies as r
            LEFT JOIN user as u ON r.user_id=u.user_id 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_discussion as d ON r.discussion_id = d.discussion_id where r.discussion_id in (". implode(',',  array_map('intval', $id)) .")";

    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

this below function will send value to upper function

```
    public function getId(){
        $sql="select discussion_id from tbl_discussion";
        $query=  $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: php is irrelevant, but it would help if you could add some example data so we see what's in the tables

Comment: in table of discussion i have id with 1 2 3 4
and discussion id is foreign key on replies my problem is in  getreplies() where array is only providing (1,1,1,1)

Comment: above you wrote "first 3 database row", in the comment you wrote only 1 row. Please be specific and add this information to the question by editing it. Also please include the definition of the foreign key, with specific detail about it's constraints